# Why do I get an "Access violation" in this C++ code

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following three classes:

```
class BeliefRoot
{
    std::string m_Name;
    BeliefRoot(std::string Name) : m_Name(Name)
    { }
};

template <class factType>
class Belief : public BeliefRoot
{
    factType m_Fact;
    explicit Belief(std::string UniqueName, factType InitialFact = NULL)
                                            : BeliefRoot(UniqueName), m_Fact(InitialFact)
    { }
};

template <class factType>
class BeliefSet : public Belief<factType>
{
    std::list<factType> m_Facts;
    explicit BeliefSet(std::string UniqueName) : Belief(UniqueName)
    { }
};
```

Now I want to instantiate the class `BeliefSet` two times:

```
BeliefSet<float> bSetFloat("SetFloat");
BeliefSet<std::string> bSetString("SetString");
```

The first is fine, but at the second call I get the following error:

*0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.*

Can somebody explain why this happens, but only if used with `std::string`?

Comment: If you have C++ 11 you should start using `nullptr`.  It will give you a better error as setting a non pointer tpye to `NULL` is nonsensical.

Comment: In C++, you should not be using the Macro `NULL` anymore. Use `nullptr`, or use an appropriate "zero-initializer" for whatever type you're working with.

Comment: But `factType` can become a primitive as well, like `int` for example. And in that case I am not allowed to use `nullptr`, or am I? I get the following error then: *error C2440: 'default argument': cannot convert from 'nullptr' to 'int'*

Comment: @Matthias: Use `= {}` for a default argument found by value-initialization, works for all built-in and pointer types, all aggregates, and classes with a default constructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ahh, I didn't know that. Thanks, that works and also solves my problem reported here! You can post that as an answer if you like and I will happily accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a default parameter having generic (dependent on template parameters) type, you don't want `= 0` (which is what you get with the `NULL` macro).  It'll select a converting constructor for `std::string` instead of the default constructor, and that converting constructor forbids passing a null pointer value.  The crash is a consequence of violating that precondition.

You also don't want default initialization, which leaves primitives with no initialization at all.  The C++ concept of "value-initialization" serves you well here... default construction for types with non-trivial construction, and zero initialization otherwise.

Good options then are copy-initialization from a value-initialized default, or the very handy list-initialization with an empty list, which is very short syntactically and also works for aggregates (since C++11 it gives value-initialization for scalar types, before that it was only useful for aggregates):

```
/* C++03 value-initialization */
explicit Belief(std::string UniqueName, factType InitialFact = factType())

/* list-initialization, since C++11 this also works great for scalars */
explicit Belief(std::string UniqueName, factType InitialFact = {})
```

Answer (score 1):

factType is string.  So it is equivalent to

```
string m_Fact = NULL;
```

Comment: Which selects the `const char*` constructor.... which has a precondition that the pointer is not null.

Answer (score 1):

`factType InitialFact = NULL` where `factType = std::string` will attempt to construct a `std::string` using the single argument `const char*` constructor.  Constructing a `std::string` from a `nullptr` will cause this crash.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your problem is the `=NULL`; below I describe it in detail, and also describe how to fix your code.

```
explicit BeliefSet(std::string UniqueName) :
  Belief<factType>(UniqueName)
{}
```

with `factType` = `std::string`, calls:

```
explicit Belief(
  std::string UniqueName,
  std::string InitialFact = NULL
) :
  BeliefRoot(UniqueName),
  m_Fact(InitialFact)
{}
```

and

```
std::string InitialFact = NULL
```

is illegal.  Replace with `={}`, giving you:

```
class BeliefRoot
{
  std::string m_Name;
  BeliefRoot(std::string Name):
    m_Name(Name)
  {}
};

template <class factType>
class Belief : public BeliefRoot
{
  factType m_Fact;
  explicit Belief(
    std::string UniqueName,
    factType InitialFact = {}
  ):
    BeliefRoot(UniqueName),
    m_Fact(InitialFact)
  {}
};

template <class factType>
class BeliefSet : public Belief<factType>
{
  std::list<factType> m_Facts;
  explicit BeliefSet(std::string UniqueName):
    Belief(UniqueName)
  {}
};
```

and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what `BeliefSet<std::string>` resolves to at compiletime:

```
//We're appending __string to indicate how the type will (roughly) be represented at compiletime.
class Belief__string : public BeliefRoot
{
    std::string m_Fact;
    explicit Belief(std::string UniqueName, std::string InitialFact = 0)
                                            : BeliefRoot(UniqueName), m_Fact(InitialFact)
    { }
};


class BeliefSet__string : public Belief__string
{
    std::list<std::string> m_Facts;
    explicit BeliefSet(std::string UniqueName) : Belief(UniqueName)
    { }
};
```

So the immediately suspicious code is in the intermediate class: `std::string InitialFact = 0`. This is poorly formed, but what's almost certainly happening is the string is trying to have a null pointer assigned to it. Strings can receive `const char *` types for construction, so it may be trying to read from this null pointer, and immediately failing due to dereferencing `null`.

Comment: There's no assignment here, no initialization.  Other than that you are correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt I pointed out in my post where the initialization is taking place: `std::string InitialFact = 0`.

Comment: @Ximera: Yes you did, but you called it assignment.  Direct quote "what's almost certainly happening is the string is trying to have a null pointer **assigned** to it"